# How do I associate an AWS EC2 instance with a purchased reserved instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We’ve purchased an Amazon Web Services (AWS) reserved instance for an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instance that is critical to our infrastructure. This instance starts and stops every day at certain time interval.

I see that purchasing a reserved instance 'guarantees' that this instance will reliably start even when AWS is under heavy load, but is there any way to specifically tie this reserved instance to the instance we want to associate with it?

What happens if we add another instance that matches the exact criteria of the reserved instance we’ve purchased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied in Naveen's answer, there is no direct way to associate an instance with a reservation.

If you want the reliability, then you must launch instances with unique set of properties (instance type, az and AMI). There is no other way at the moment.

This is supposed to be a comment in Naveen's reply. But as I had no reputation yet to commen, I am adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry or do anything in associating the instance and the purchased Reserved Instance; all those are done automatically by AWS.

The reserved Instance is purely a **billing and cost related** and it doesn't relate to the technology aspect of an EC2 instance. If any of your running instance matches with any of your purchased Reserved Instance then you benefit from the reduced costing. There isn't any commitment on the SLA or changes at the Instance level which involves Reserved Instance. The same case works when you have 2 reserved instances; if there 2 instances running in your account which matches your reserved instance purchase they the reduced cost would be applied.

**Analogy - Super Market Coupon Offer**

> If the Offer Says, buy 2 units of Product A and get one Product B
>   absolutely Free. So you look into the offer and take 2 units of
>   Product A and one Unit of Product B. During the billing as well, the
>   Point of Sales Person also doesn't look into each and every product
>   and try to check it offers; rather he or she directly keeps scaning
>   each and every product against the bar-code scanner and that't it -
>   when these 3 are scanned, the price for Free-Product is automatically
>   reversed.
>
> So similarly, you buy the Reserved Instance (Coupon) choosing the AMI,
>   Region, AZ, Duration etc. You would do all your tech stuff as usual
>   like deploying, patching, monitoring etc. During the billing, if the
>   instance(s) you launched matches the Reserved Instance, then the
>   Reserved pricing would be applied; if not that would be charged at
>   'On-Demand-Pricing'.
>
> If there is a **mismatch between what instance you are running and what instance you have reserved; you will not be using the benefit of Reserved-Instance** pricing
>   and be charged with **On-Demand-Pricing**. Also you will be wasting the
>   investment done for the **Reserved-Instance**

Comment: Thanks for the response Naveen!

I'm looking to benefit more from the reliability aspects of a reserved instance that AWS promotes.

If we have 1 reserved instance and 1 instance that matches the criteria of this reserved instance, AWS guarantees that this instance will always boot.

Does that mean if we have 1 reserved instance and 2 instances that match the criteria of this reserved instance, that the AWS guarantee will only apply to the first instance started?